How can I using Facebook marketing API (SDK) upload campaigns by CSV?
in Facebook Ads Manager we can easely upload list of campaigns by uploading CSV file.
How can we do it using Facebook SDK?
(I see only option to bulk event upload - create manualy campaings, adsets, ads, creatives.. , but no by one CSV file, like in Ads Manager)

